# Html content getting disappeared in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, fabricjs

I have a project which was built with javascript, fabricjs and jquery

Here's the link of the working project: http://vintagelogos.clickysoft.com/design-editor/?product=12&product_cms=29

When you change any option in the dropdown of "Drumhead Size" you'll notice that the whole section is getting disappeared, but when you resize the window, it will turn back to normal section.

**Note:**
This is working well in Firefox or IE and it was working fine in chrome as well.

But now I don't know why I am facing this issue.

**Please Help**

Comment: You should post a self-contained piece of code demonstrating the issue; links to full external sites are not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `position: absolute;` from `div#LumiseDesign div#lumise-left .lumise-tab-body-wrp` should fix this.

Comment: Wow. You just saved my day. Thank you so much.